# How to over come OS error in mac when using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, macos

I use Jupiter on my mac book pro (os-catalina) and when i use pandas to read a CSV file , after the path of file in program i get an OS error. can this be resolved ?

This is how the error is displayed:

[image]

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
r_filenameCSV='/Users/manubharathmurali/Documents/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv'
csv_read=pd.read_csv(r_filenameCSV)
csv_read
```

File name: `Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv`

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: Same goes for exceptions/stacktraces. A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample of your csv file which throws out this error?

Comment: Hmm, OSError means that the file was not accessible. Common problems are a typo in the path, or a permission problem

Comment: @KarthickMohanraj i have the same kind of problem with any CSV file.

Comment: @SergeBallesta any website for help on getting clear with the permissions?

Comment: might be a permission issue. Can you goto /Users/manubharathmurali/Documents/ and open jupyter notebook in this folder. Then read csv without giving path.

Comment: The one that contains references for your OS...

Comment: To check permissons, open a terminal with Jupyter and write `ls -al /Users/manubharathmurali/Documents/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv`. Add the output to your post.